# Attribute application@label value=(tst) from (unknown) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

getting this error Attribute application@label value=(tst) from (unknown) in flutter

```
Attribute application@label value=(tst) from (unknown)
is also present at [com.wuhenzhizao:titlebar:1.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41 value= 
(@string/app_name).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at 
 AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-41:19 to override.
```